# C++ Is there any way to classify parts of a text file then use them seperately?

Tags: c++, vector, text, filestream

I am currently trying to do my college homework, we are studying file streams and vectors in C++ right now, our task is long but I will just try to explain my main problem:

We need to read multiple text files and get information and store them in vectors,
anyways, in our first text file, there are parts we need to read like this:

***HOMEWORK*** 
00011234 84 
00012341 90 
00012481 100

***MIDTERM*** 
00011234 55 
00012341 99 
00012481 50 
(student Id, grade)

etc...  In our task, we need to get 10% of homework grade, 20% of midterm grade and 30% of final grade, and then take the sum of grades related with student id's.

My question is: is there any way to read by iteration or group these informations, and use them to take related percentages?
(btw we didn't learn classes/structs/pointers yet, so it's forbidden to use them in our task, just vectors, fstream, sstream, string libraries.)
Also, there are multiple homework grades for a student, or only 1 homework grade etc. (We need to take percentages and sum all grades of that student)

Comment: The right way would be to use an associative container mapping student IDs to a list of grades. Have you recently covered hash tables?

Comment: I think your question should be a bit more focused. As it stands, you are basically asking us to do your homework for you, which is not what this is site for.

Comment: Are you certain that you cannot use a `struct`? Aggregating student IDs and the various scores would be a logical solution I would expect of a beginning programming assignment. Not aggregating is an exercise in frustration  that would lead to making people worse programmers rather than better.

Comment: the thing with reading files is [it's astronomically slow](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-infinite-space-between-words/) compared to most of the other things you do with a computer. Typically you read as much as possible, everything if you have the storage, into memory and search the memory. If you repeatedly search through files, you suffer the costs of reading the files over and over again. This is likely what the instructor expects you to use `vector` for.

Comment: @Frank Actually my question was about to have an Idea on how can I seperate each part of the file that I read, not making you do my homework. My question relates with 10-15% of my homework, I know how I can do the rest. I know how this site works, thank you for your kind comment but I don't need critics. It was just a simple question about something I don't know.

Comment: @user4581301 Thank you for your advice, but the main reason why we can't use structs is, we didn't cover about it yet. My instructor wants us to do it with the information we got so far. The problem is: I don't know to get the specific parts of a file. If I could assume about the line number of text files, it would be easier, but there are multiple files we can try our code, but they vary a lot.

Comment: Take Frank's warning as it was intended: As a warning. Currently we can only respond with generalities, not quality answers.

Comment: @user4581301 No we didn't cover hash tables. We covered very basics of vector/array/fstream/sstream lately.

Comment: @Oprasis, What I'm getting at is: As long as know how to read a file line-by-line, and how to do basic flow control (if/else/while), then it's really just a matter of writing the logic you desire using these tools, it's kind of impossible to answer this as is without giving you the actual code. If you had a more focused question, we'd be able to answer without just writing your code for you.

Comment: If you can have multiple different types of data in a file, for example a file contains a mix of assignment scores, midterm scores and final scores, there is no simple magic to tell them apart. You'd have to read and store as one type until you find the delimiter separating the type, and then store as this new type until you find another delimiter.

Comment: @Frank My question was simple: I don't know if there is a way to use getline function until a specific line. For a week I am trying my best, but I felt that there may be something I don't know about files or strings. I am trying to have an idea, I am not seeking an exact answer. That's why I didn't paste my code here. I hope I could explain what my problem is.

Comment: @user4581301 thank you, that inspired me a lot, I will try few new algorithms.

Comment: @Oprasis Yes, this is a much clearer and focused question that can be answered as-is. Thank you very much for the clarification.

Comment: There is no way without using stuff you're probably not allowed to use yet ([stream iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator), for example). Regardless you can't really skip around in a text file looking for lines because he computer still needs to search for those lines at least once. And if you have to search for them, you might as well read and process what's between them so that you don't have to do it again and again.

Comment: @user4581301 I can read the whole file, it's not the problem. The problem is, after I read the whole text file, how can I understand which line belongs to which assessment? How can I use lines between homework and midterm headers to understand that it's homework grades.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know if there is a way to use getline function until a specific line.

There are many ways of going about that, but a simple one is to use the `break` keyword to exit out of a loop when a certain condition is met.

```
std::ifstream file_stream ("file.text");
std::string line_text;

while(getline(file_stream, line_text)) {
 if(line_text == "MIDTERM") { // or whatever other test makes sense for your situation.
    // This will make the program skip to immediately after the loop.
    break;
 }

 // Handle otherwise
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would probably instead use an approach based on something called a **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine instead, but for your purposes and where you are in your learning process, I'd recommend keeping it very simple.

Comment: Funny thing is: we are not allowed to use break or continue as well =)  What a learning environment isn't it?

Comment: When  you can't `break`, pop the code into a function and return from the function.